# Rails Interaction with Riot API, Returning average of team probability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, methods, model, haml

for a small project I was trying to develop an application with rails to return the probability of a team in League of Legends to win depending on the individual players win rate. I am interacting with the Riot API and can return a summoner and the probability of winning with their champion. I figured out that I want the method to add together all the players win ratio(their champion_probability) from the team entered and then return the average.

Here is my Tteam model (where I am trying to build the method)

```
class Tteam < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'riotsecondapi'
  before_save :downcase_players

  before_save :mod_champ_save


  def self.return_id(name)
    api = RiotApi.new
    info = api.get_summoner_id(name)
    info[name]["id"]
  end

  def self.return_summoner_champion_list(summoner_name)
    id = return_id(summoner_name)
    api = RiotApi.new
    full_stat = api.get_full_stats(id)
    full_stat["champions"]
  end

  def self.get_champion_id(champ_name)
  api = RiotApi.new
  champs = api.get_champion
  champs["data"][champ_name]
  end

  def self.determine_champion_probability(summoner_name, champ_name)
  champion_ids = return_summoner_champion_list(summoner_name).collect{|player| player["id"]}
   desired_champ_id = get_champion_id(champ_name)
   winrate = 0.0

   if champion_ids.include?(desired_champ_id)
     hash = Hash[champion_ids.map.with_index.to_a]
     champ_array_location = hash[desired_champ_id]

 player_stat = return_summoner_champion_list(summoner_name)[champ_array_location]["stats"]
 total_played = player_stat["totalSessionsPlayed"]
 total_won = player_stat["totalSessionsWon"]
     winrate = (total_won.to_f / total_played.to_f)
     winrate.round(2) * 100
   else
     winrate = 0.5 * 100
   end
  end



 def self.team_probability
    team_winrate = determine_champion_probability(p1,c1) + determine_champion_probability(p2, c2), + determine_champion_probability(p3, c3)
    team_winrate
  end
```

My method team_probability keeps returning the error "undefined local variable or method `p1' for #". So I am guessing that using those variables will not work here.

Here is my my Tteam controller

```
class TteamsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
    @tteam = Tteam.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @tteam = Tteam.new(tteams_params)
    @tteam.save
    redirect_to @tteam
  end

  private
  def tteams_params
    params.require(:tteam).permit(:p1, :p2, :p3, :c1, :c2, :c3)
  end
end
```

and the show view for my team (this is in haml)

```
Team1
%p
  In any given ranked game, the probability of
  %b= @tteam.p1
  winning with
  %b= @tteam.c1
  is
  = Tteam.determine_champion_probability(@tteam.p1, @tteam.c1)
  &#37

%p
  In any given ranked game, the probability of
  %b= @tteam.p2
  winning with
  %b= @tteam.c2
  is
  = Tteam.determine_champion_probability(@tteam.p2, @tteam.c2)
  &#37

  %p
    In any given ranked game, the probability of
    %b= @tteam.p3
    winning with
    %b= @tteam.c3
    is
    = Tteam.determine_champion_probability(@tteam.p3, @tteam.c3)
    &#37
  %p
  Your team's overall probability of winning is...
  = Tteam.team_probability
  &#37
```

At the end of the view I am trying to call the team_probability method on the class to return the sum of the players champion_probability for now. If anyone has an idea on how I can fix this undefined local variable error that would be a big help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, p1 and c1 are indeed undefined variables. You can pass them as parameters to the Tteam.team_probability method.